# How can I display a bitmap/icon on an XP style button

Tags: c++, mfc, button, bitmap, icons

I have a small (6x9) graphic that I want to draw on a CButton. I have managed to get this to work using ::LoadImage and CButton::SetBitmap.
The problem is that when I put the bitmap on the button it is no-longer drawn as an 'XP style' button. I.e. it does not have rounded corners.

How can I draw a bitmap (or an icon) on a button without the button losing the XP style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it with owner draw. Use CMFCButton which has much better support for bitmapped buttons, even with transparency.

Comment: Also needed the following link in OnInitDialog to work:
CMFCVisualManager::SetDefaultManager(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCVisualManagerWindows));